# How can I get frequency and pitch from a monophonic wav file using matlab?

Tags: matlab, audio, wav

I was given an assignment for my Music data mining course that we only have 2 days to do. I can't figure out how to finish question 4 (below). The other 4 questions were extremely easy to do, but this one makes no sense. Nothing she has taught us in the course helps, and no internet sources have been able to shed any light. I understand how to get the pitch name once I have the frequency of the note, but I'm not sure how to get the frequency. Any help would be appreciated.

Full question:

Write a Matlab program named hw2q4xxx.m (xxx is the last 3 digits of your n-number) 
to identify the pitch containing in wave files.

The program will be executed using the command:

hw2q4xxx(‘input.wav’)

Input: 
• input.wav – a monophonic wave file containing the sound of a single pitch.

Output: 
• Display pitch name and register on the screen. For example, displaying C4 for the 
wave file containing a pitch with frequency around 265 Hz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When loaded into Matlab, .wav files usually contain a data vector and a sampling frequency.  You will need to perform a spectral estimate or an FFT to determine the frequency content.  I would recommend using something like pwelch, which will perform a power spectral estimate for your data.  Once loaded, you can try something along these lines:

```
pwelch(data,[],[],1024,fs)
```

This will plot the spectral estimate and should contain a strong tone at the frequency of interest.

You can also get a better spectrum by using some windowing techniques, for example, using a hamming window will reduce a lot of the ripple you see in the spectrum plots. This would be done using something like this:

```
NFFT = 1024;
pwelch(data,hamming(NFFT),[],NFFT,fs)
```

Increasing the size of NFFT will provide better frequency resolution.  You can play around with that too (for example you could try NFFT=1024*10).

To extract the frequency information, you can use the findpeaks function.  Give this code a try:

```
NFFT = 1024*10;

out = pwelch(data,hamming(NFFT),[],NFFT,fs);
[pks locs] = findpeaks(out);
indx = find(pks == max(pks));
indx_max = locs(indx);

f = indx_max/length(out) * (fs/2);
```

This will save the pwelch data to the vector "out".  It will then find all of the local maxima "pks" along with their locations "locs".  You can then find the maximum local peak with the find command and determine which index within the vector "out" it is located. The last line converts from index to frequency.

Comment: Hey thanks, this is awesome! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the explanation as well. I have the code in place to translate the frequency to a note, so I really appreciate you helping me understand this. 

Thanks again!